# String back into byte array - not working

Tags: c#, encoding, byte, arrays

I have a stream that gets converted into a byte array.

I then take that bye array and turn it into a string.

When I try to turn that string back into a byte array it is not correct...see the code below.

```
     private void Parse(Stream stream, Encoding encoding)
     {
        // Read the stream into a byte array
        byte[] allData = ToByteArray(stream);

        // Copy to a string for header parsing
        string allContent = encoding.GetString(allData);

        //This does not convert back right - just for demo purposes, not how the code is used
        allData = encoding.GetBytes(allContent);
    }

    private byte[] ToByteArray(Stream stream)
    {
        byte[] buffer = new byte[32768];
        using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            while (true)
            {
                int read = stream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
                if (read <= 0)
                    return ms.ToArray();
                ms.Write(buffer, 0, read);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you show the code of ToByteArray(Stream s) pls.

Comment: Can you be a bit more specific than 'not correct'?

Comment: Which encoding do you pass to the `Parse()` method? And which encoding does the data in the `Stream` use?

Comment: Can you elaborate on what is different? It might be that just the first few bytes, which can contain encoding type information, are different.

Comment: I am using Encoding.UTF8 for the encoding

Comment: When encoded from the stream allData =  {byte[25360]} 
after I to convert the string back to the byte array allData = {byte[44771]}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without having more information, I'm quite certain that this is a text encoding issue. Most likely, the text encoding in the stream is different than the encoding specified as your parameter. This will result in different values at the byte level.

Here's a few good articles that explains why you're seeing what you're seeing.

- [The Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer Absolutely, Positively Must Know About Unicode and Character Sets (No Excuses!)](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html)
- [How to Determine Text File Encoding](http://codesnipers.com/?q=node/68)
- [General questions, relating to UTF or Encoding Form](http://unicode.org/faq/utf_bom.html)

Comment: even though they both use the same encoding?  and any idea how to make it work?  Basically I am parsing a multipart/form-data which has a image in it and some values

Comment: Can you compare the two byte arrays and see what is different? Are they different lengths (not the array size itself, but the contents of the array)? Are only the first 2 bytes different? UTF-16 can be encoded as little-endian or big-endian, the first 2 bytes signal which is used: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark#cite_note-11

Answer (score 2):

I think changing the `ToByteArray` method to use a `StreamReader` that matches the encoding should work in this case, although without seeing more of the code I can't be certain.

```
private byte[] ToByteArray(Stream stream, System.Text.Encoding encoding)
{
    using(var sr = new StreamReader(stream, encoding))
    {
        return encoding.GetBytes(sr.ReadToEnd());
    }
}
```

**EDIT**
Since you're working with image data, you should use `Convert.ToBase64String` to convert the `byte[]` to a `string`. You can then use `Convert.FromBase64String` decode to convert back into a `byte[]`. The reason `encoding.GetBytes` doesn't work is because there may be some data in the `byte[]` that cannot be represented as a string for that encoding.

```
private void Parse(Stream stream, Encoding encoding)
{
    byte[] allData = ToByteArray(stream);

    string allContent = Convert.ToBase64String(allData);  

    allData = Convert.FromBase64String(allContent);
}
```

Comment: When I do it this way it doesn't create the image right when trying to writeing it out to a file

Comment: @Adam Can you post more of the code then? How are you trying to write to disk?

Comment: Here is how I write the bytes to disk

if (obj.FileContents != null)
                    {
                        int ArraySize = obj.FileContents.Length;
                        string outputFile = @"C:\Temp\upload" + i.ToString() + ".jpg";
                        FileStream fs = new FileStream(outputFile, FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Write);
                        fs.Write(obj.FileContents, 0, ArraySize);
                        fs.Close();
                    }

Comment: And the stream comes a HTML form being submitted that is enctype="multipart/form-data"

Comment: @Adam Are you sure the image data isn't base64 encoded in the multipart/form message? If it was then you would need to decode before saving to disk.

Comment: @Adam, One other thing, is this data being uploaded through ASP.NET? It seems like you're trying to handle a form post, and if you are under ASP.NET there are easier ways of reading the file than going directly to the RequestStream (if that is what's happening).

Comment: Yea because it works right now if I don't put it back in the byte array

Comment: @Adam Please see the edit to my answer. If you need to go from byte[] to string for image data, Base64 encoding is the way to go.

Comment: well the I was using base 64 encoding was so I could then run regular expressions on the string to parse the image easily.  Any more thoughts?

Comment: @Adam Well, that's kind of outside the scope of your original question. I'd be happy to take a shot at it but you'll have to update the original question with exactly what you're trying to do. I'm just trying to provide a way to turn a byte[] into a string back into a byte[], which is what the original question was about.